# Ignoring certain tags for web scraping in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm new to web scraping and HTML. I intend to web scrape the first paragraph from a randomly generated Wikipedia article (which contains an introduction to the article). For this, I have written the following code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

while True:
    
    url = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find(class_="firstHeading").text

    print(f"\n\n{title} : View Topic?\n")
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s" % title

    etr=soup.find('div',class_='mw-parser-output')
    abr=etr.p.text

    print("\n",abr)
```

This does not show the intended output for *some* wikipedia articles which contain an additional line

```
<p class="mw-empty-elt"></p> == $0
```

which is supposedly executed instead of the follow-up required paragraph tag.

```
<p>..</p>
```

of who's the text content is required to be displayed.
[Website's HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Ppq.png)

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgh6c.png)

Also, is there a way to remove the quotations in the superscripts when displaying the output
[like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13VP7.png) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `etr.find_next("p", class_=None)` to find `<p>` tags without `class=`.

To remove `<sub>` tags, you can use `.extract()` method.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

while True:

    url = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find(class_="firstHeading").text

    print(f"\n\n{title} : View Topic?\n")
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s" % title

    etr = soup.find("div", class_="mw-parser-output")
    abr = etr.find_next("p", class_=None)  # <-- get only <p> without any class=

    if abr:
        for sup in abr.select("sup"):
            sup.extract()  # <-- remove <sup> tags

    print("\n", abr)
```

Prints:

```html
Paul Bara : View Topic?


 <p><b>Paul Bara</b>  is a <a href="/wiki/Grower_Champagne" title="Grower Champagne">Grower Champagne</a> producer and an original member of the <a href="/wiki/Club_Tr%C3%A9sors_de_Champagne" title="Club Trésors de Champagne">Club Trésors de Champagne</a>.
Paul Bara is a seventh-generation <a href="/wiki/Family_business" title="Family business">family business</a> currently managed by Chantale Bara. Champagne Paul Bara is one of the few Grower Champagne producers in <a href="/wiki/Bouzy" title="Bouzy">Bouzy</a>.  The planted vineyards are 11 <a href="/wiki/Hectare" title="Hectare">hectares</a> in area. Only the first <a href="/wiki/Pressing_(wine)" title="Pressing (wine)">pressing</a> of the grapes is used in Paul Bara wines.
</p>


The Neon God: Part 1 – The Rise : View Topic?


 <p><i><b>The Neon God: Part 1 – The Rise</b></i>, is the first act of a two-part <a href="/wiki/Rock_opera" title="Rock opera">rock opera</a> by the American <a href="/wiki/Heavy_metal_music" title="Heavy metal music">heavy metal</a> band  <a href="/wiki/W.A.S.P._(band)" title="W.A.S.P. (band)">W.A.S.P.</a>. The songs on the album narrate the story of an abused and orphaned boy named Jesse, who finds that he has the ability to read and manipulate people. The second part was released on the album titled <i><a class="mw-redirect" href="/wiki/The_Neon_God:_Part_2_-_The_Demise" title="The Neon God: Part 2 - The Demise">The Neon God: Part 2 - The Demise</a></i>.
</p>

...
```